# Pattern search in a file,

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

pattern will be present as a column in another file. 
file_1.txt

```
pattern1  pattern2
pattern3  pattern4
pattern5  pattern6
```

cat  Mainfile.txt

```
mine line as pattern1 and pattern2
mine line2 as pattern5 and pattern6
other then that nothing should dispaly
unwanted line
```

final ouput_file.txt

```
mine line as pattern1 and pattern2
mine line2 as pattern5 and pattern6
```

if both the pattern present then only display the line, problem is that pattern is present in colomnwise in file_1.txt

Answer (score 0):

this is bordering on obvious

```
sed -s 's:\([^ ]*\)[ ]*\([^ ]*\):/\1.*\2/p:' file_1.txt  | sed -f - -n Mainfile.txt
```

where

- `sed -s 's:\([^ ]*\)[ ]*\([^ ]*\):/\1.*\2/p:' file_1.txt`

will give a list of sed  command

```
/pattern1.*pattern2/p
/pattern3.*pattern4/p
/pattern5.*pattern6/p
```

- `sed -f - -n Mainfile.txt`

where

- `-f -` will use previous file (from `|` to `-`) as command file,
- `-n` do no print line (unless matched)

Comment: my file contains lacks of entry need faster command